# Charlie goes on vacation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story, geography

> ADAM: Hey Benny, check it out. It's a letter from Charlie. He's going on vacation!
>   BENNY: Cool! Where is he going?
>   ADAM: No idea. Maybe the letter will say. Let's see...
>
> > *Hey guys! So I finally left for my vacation. I know you're itching to find out where I'm going, so I'll give you some clues. Maybe you can figure it out!*
>
> BENNY: Okay, if I didn't care before, I *have* to know now.
>
> > *For my first stop, I will be flying to Vienna. Hope to snorkel in the Great Barrier Reef and maybe see some kangaroos as well!*
>
> ADAM: Ahahahahah, kangaroos in Vienna? This guy was always garbage at geography.
>   BENNY: There is absolutely 100% chance his trip will go hilariously wrong. Let's see what else he writes.
>
> > *My second stop is Luang Prabang. Looking forward to an in-depth experience of an African megacity!*
>
> ADAM: Hahah, African? Pretty close there, buddy. Not!
>   BENNY: No way Charlie is *this* stupid. He has to be messing with us.
>
> > *Next up, I'm flying to the exciting Andalusia. Looking to chill out at the beach, enjoy a margarita and swim in the warm Caribbean water.*
>
> ADAM: Just wait a minute. These destinations are all over the globe. Charlie's vacation is just two weeks. There's no way he can visit all of these places.
>   BENNY: Yeah, he has to be playing us. Maybe there's a hidden message or something.
>
> > *After that I'm headed to Togo to check out the historical sights. You can expect a postcard with the picture of my face and the Colosseum in the background!*
>
> ADAM: Do you understand any of this?
>   BENNY: No clue. What's the last place he's visiting?
>
> > *Last but not least, I'm making a stop in Niamey. Check out the Igbo homelands and the Niger delta. After that I'll be on my way back home.*
>
> BENNY: Well, at least he's a bit closer this time. Still no cigar, though.
>
> > *Anyway, I've given you some clues. Maybe you can figure out where I'm actually going! Hahahaha! See you in two weeks! Love, Charlie*
>
> ADAM: Okay. We'll never hear the end of it if we don't figure this out.
>   BENNY: I agree. Where on Earth can he be headed??

What is Charlie's actual destination? Looking for the name of a country.

Comment: nice puzzle,really enjoyed it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm guessing he's really going to

> Algeria

The trick is that

> each clue gives multiple similar answers. We use the letters that are different in the second answer to make the final answer

For my first stop, I will be flying to Vienna. Hope to snorkel in the Great Barrier Reef and maybe see some kangaroos as well!

> Austria and Australia, so AL

My second stop is Luang Prabang. Looking forward to an in-depth experience of an African megacity!

> Laos and Lagos. So G

Next up, I'm flying to the exciting Andalusia. Looking to chill out at the beach, enjoy a margarita and swim in the warm Caribbean water.

> Granada and Grenada. So E.

After that I'm headed to Togo to check out the historical sights. You can expect a postcard with the picture of my face and the Colosseum in the background!

> Lomé (Togolese capital) and Rome. So R.

Last but not least, I'm making a stop in Niamey. Check out the Igbo homelands and the Niger delta. After that I'll be on my way back home.

> Niger and Nigeria. So IA

Comment: <hide> As an aside, mathematically, for two words w1 and w2, we find the union of the set differences: (w1-w2) U (w2-w1). (Each word is a set of letters, the order doesn't matter). </hide>

Comment: Was misled by Spain - Port of Spain for the longest time!

Comment: Actually, once I'd worked out the first two, I spent a fair while trying to make the rest fit rot13(Nytneir). I'd even started the explanation with the answer as rot13(Cbeghtny). It was only when I skipped the middle two and got the last one that I realised I was on the wrong track. Really good puzzle @jafe